# What are interesting properties of totally bounded uniform spaces?

Tags: uniform-spaces

I work on *reloids*, a generalization of uniform spaces.

As such I am interested about properties of totally bounded uniform spaces.

My question: What are interesting properties of totally bounded uniform spaces? (The more theorems/propositions you give, the better.)

Comment: By the way, [here](http://webfile.ru/6500745) is a book “Uniform spaces” by J.R. Isbell (MSM012, AMS, 1964)

Comment: [About totally bounded complete quasi-uniform spaces](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1101995/non-symmetric-version-of-compact-totally-bounded-complete).

Answer (score 4):

As far as I remember, these are equivalent for a uniform space $(X,\mathcal D)$:

1. $(X,\mathcal D)$ is totally bounded, that is, for each entourage $D\in \mathcal D$, there are $x_1,...,x_n\in X$ with $D[x_1]\cup...\cup D[x_n]=X$.
2. $(X,\mathcal D)$ is precompact, that is, it has a compact completion.
3. Every completion of $(X,\mathcal D)$ is compact.
4. Every net in $X$ has a Cauchy subnet.

Also every Tychonoff space has a compatible totally bounded uniformity.

Comment: The way round: uniformities are a generalization of proximities

Comment: How (1) follows from the Wikipedia's definition of total boundness? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_bounded_space

Comment: OK, (1) is proved. But I have some trouble proving the reverse implication.